# How to add category image/thumbnail to navigation in Magento > 1.7

Tags: php, magento

I've seen a few solutions to this funcionality request for versions of Magento < 1.7 but none for the version I am using. Since in v1.7 the navigation template was moved from `top.phtml` to `\app\design\frontend\THEME\TEMPLATENAME\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml` the solutions I have seen are no longer applicable.

I just want to be able to output the category image (uploaded through the admin interface) within the native category menu dropdown. The dropdown structure and layout is done and works as I want it, minus the image.

Comment: It's not clear if you mean versions newer than 1.7 or older than 1.7. Your title says one but question says the other.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override / replace Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer.

Simplest way is to copy Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer (app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php) to:

```
 app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php
```

You can then modify: **_addCategoriesToMenu()**

Add the image into the data:

```
$categoryData = array(
    'image_url' => $category->getImageUrl(), // or thumbnail if you wanted.
    'name' => $category->getName(),
    'id' => $nodeId,
    'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
    'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category)
);
```

this data will then be available inside the Navigation block. you will also need to override this block: copy  app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php
```

modify the **_getHtml()** method to add the image into the markup as required.

the image url will be available via the node, like this:

```
$child->getImageUrl(); // or
$child->getData('image_url');
```

Comment: I could NOT get this to work. Your recommendation returns nothing. Oh and the `getHtml()` method is now located in `/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`. The closest I've come to a solution is on the category page itself, outputting the thumbnail using `<img alt="" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/category/' . $_category->getThumbnail(); ?>">` but this doesn't help much when trying to get a subcat thumbnail in the nav menu.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is for Magento -1.8.*

In Model file. (/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php)

Update following code in Function Name: _addCategoriesToMenu

```
 $categoryData = array( 
        'name' => $category->getName(),
        'id' => $nodeId,
        'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
        'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
        'thumbnail' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail()

);
```

Then go into Html folder. (app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php)

Update the following line of code at line 128 in

Function name: _getHtml

```
$urls = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$child->getData('thumbnail');
$img = '<img src="'.$urls.'" />';

$html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
        . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . ' </span> '.$img.' </a>';
```